# Generating Surrogates only if the ID value is missing

Tags: oracle11g

Is there a simple query which will let me insert auto generated values into ID field only if the ID is missing? I don't want to overwrite what is already there in ID column in my employees table.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger:

```
create trigger trg_name 
before insert
on YOUR_TABLE_HERE
for each row
begin
  if :new.id is null 
  then 
    :new.id = YOUR_FUNCTION_TO_GENERATE_ID_OR_NEXT_SEQ_NO;
  end if;
end trg_name;
```

Make sure you don't query your table when you generate next id value else your table will be mutating.